# Is there a reason this break statement doesn't break out of the for loop?

Tags: arduino

I'm going crazy. I know that the loop is entered, but there must be something i'm doing that prevents the break from exiting the for loop. Any ideas?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
  if (users[i][1][j] != arr[j]){
    Serial.println("Mismatch");
    break;
  }
  else if (j == 11){
    Serial.println("Entire card read correctly");
    return i;
  }
}
```

[For loop - break nonfunctional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVyYP.png)

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image.

Comment: is "Mismatch" getting printed?

Comment: Yes, mismatch is being printed.

Comment: Once "Mismatch" is printed, the loop will exit.  But that doesn't mean it isn't being re-entered, making it appear that the loop hasn't exited.  You haven't included enough context to diagnose this, but here are a couple things to check:  (1)  Is this code embedded in an outer loop?  (2) Is the function that contains the code being called more than once?

Comment: Arduino is not C code.

Answer (score 0):

The code was being reentered from an outside loop.